# Nothing happens when including library

Tags: javascript, html, css

I"m trying to include a [grid library from github](https://github.com/hootsuite/grid). The problem is, nothing happens when I do it.

Here's the way I did it:

```
var myGrid = new GridList(document.getElementById('container'), {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  lanes: 3
});
```

The weird thing is, I don't even get an error!

#### JSFiddle

```js
var myGrid = new GridList(document.getElementById('container'), {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  lanes: 3
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hootsuite/grid/master/src/gridList.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li id="01">Number 01</li>
  <li id="02">Number 02</li>
  <li id="03">Number 03</li>
  <li id="04">Number 04</li>
  <li id="05">Number 05</li>
  <li id="06">Number 06</li>
  <li id="07">Number 07</li>
  <li id="08">Number 08</li>
  <li id="09">Number 09</li>
  <li id="10">Number 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, yeah. If you read the documentation, the main `GridList` class is just an abstraction for handling the relationships. It doesn't affect the DOM.

Comment: @MikeC I didn't fully understand the docs. What's the point of the javascript `GridList` for then?

Comment: To give you an easy way of handling the intricacies of organizing the grid. Then you can use that data to render it yourself. If you read more of the documentation, you'll see that they have a jQuery plugin that does some of the rendering for you.